# Where clause to exclude criteria and include null

Tags: sql

I think this is probably an easy one but cannot work out how to get the answer. I noticed on a query I have written some expected data being excluded. When I looked at the where clause I noticed that although I have:

```
Where SP.Type <> 'No Exposure'
```

I'm also excluding the rows that have null in this field. The reason I am using the <> is becuase there are about 5 differnet options so better exclude one than include 5.

What would be the best way to execute this criteria but also include the null values?

Comment: Did you try adding `or SP.Type is null`?

Comment: What is your database platform? Although it doesn't matter here, please tell us next time.

Comment: `NULL` is neither equal(`=`) nor unequal(`<>`) to any existing value. It's undefined.

Comment: "What would be the best way to execute this criteria but also include the null values?"  That depends on how the nulls are created... Are the null records a result of an outer join?  If so move the where clause to the join criteria `on` ..... `and sp.type <> 'No Exposure'`  If they are just in the columnar data then use an `or` clause `Where (sp.type <> 'No Exposure' or Sp.Type is null)`  ()'s matter if you have additional criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 2 options, depending on your database platform.  Since we don't know that, we can at least give you those 2 options.

The first option is to include a check for null in your `WHERE` clause:

```
Where SP.Type <> 'No Exposure' OR SP.Type is null
```

The second option is to use `COALESCE` like this:

```
Where Coalesce(SP.Type, '') <> 'No Exposure'
```

Comment: Who could know, no dbms specified here... But I'd say it's not expensive at all.

Comment: Typically not.  But since the DBMS isn't specified, we have no idea if there is a query optimizer that might come up with a better execution plan for either scenario.

Comment: Hi Douglas, the Coalesce worked a treat! I did try the SP.Type is null but it seemed to overwrite my other where criteria and just bring back NULLs Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use in where clause

```
Where SP.Type <> 'No Exposure' OR SP.Type is null
```